# Customizing filter criteria search of a view

Tags: views

I've got a view with an exposed to users filter criteria ajax search. I want to customize it somehow and **link a specific search phrase to a specific node**.

any idea on how to do that? any way around without getting my hands dirty with coding?

Answer (score 0):

1. use hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
2. if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-page...'
3. $form['my_link_element'] = array('#markup' => l(t('Seacrh word taken from form_state'),'node/5'));

Comment: thank you gaydabura,
could u elaborate more though on what should I replace on 3? what should 'my_link_element' be? =)

Comment: "my_link_element" - internal name of you element on form - can be any you want.

Comment: Actually I think you misunderstood my problem. =)
I'll try to rephrase.

I give the possibility to the users to search and find a node via this view search filter. What I want to achieve is that if they search "/help", for example, the only result to be a specific node that I've made. So:

I want a relationship between a specific search phrase and a node somehow.